# why the result is 2 4 6 8 10?

Tags: java

```
public class TestFileStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream output=new FileOutputStream("temp.dat");

        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            output.write(i);
        }
        output.close();
        FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream("temp.dat");
        while((input.read())!=-1){
            System.out.print(input.read()+" ");
        }
        input.close();  
    }
}
```

[This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHYyE.png)
why the result is 2 4 6 8 10? where is the 1 3 5 7 9?

Comment: You do a double read in your loop; how are you surprised of the result?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29) for read, "Reads a byte of data from this input stream. This method blocks if no input is yet available." If you would read the doc, you would have your answer. You read in bytes. :)

Comment: Thank you ! Yes, I ignore this!

Answer (score 2):

You read one byte in `(input.read())!=-1` and read another byte in `System.out.print(input.read()+" ");`.

If you want to print all of the contents, save what you read and print it.

```
public class TestFileStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream output=new FileOutputStream("temp.dat");

        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            output.write(i);
        }
        output.close();
        FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream("temp.dat");
        int data;
        while((data = input.read())!=-1){
            System.out.print(data+" ");
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every iteration you are fetching the data at two places as pointed out above once at `(input.read())!=-1` and again at `System.out.print(input.read()+" ");`